typescript Buffer type toString expected 0 arguments
I have this simple typescript code:
const y = Buffer.from("fds")
y.toString("hex")

But I am getting a tsc type error on "hex" saying Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.
The toString method takes in an argument though https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buftostringencoding-start-end
So it seems like my types are somehow not up to date for just this standard library somehow?
╰─❯ node -v
v20.12.2

╰─❯ yarn tsc -v
Version 5.3.2

I am running yarn run tsc --noEmit --p ./src --incremental"
My tsconfig
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.base.json",
  "include": ["./src/**/*", "./mmmEval"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "_build", "dist"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2020",
    "composite": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "#src/*": ["./*"]
    },
    "types": ["node"],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "plugins": [{ "name": "grats-ts-plugin" }]
  },
  "grats": {
    "graphqlSchema": "./src/gql/schema.generated.graphql",
    "tsSchema": "./src/gql/schema.generated.ts",
    "tsSchemaHeader": "// @ts-nocheck\n // This file was automatically generated and should not be edited.\n",
    "nullableByDefault": false
  },
}

tsconfig.base.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "target": "es2022",
    "lib": ["es2022", "dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext.disposable", "ESNext.Disposable"],
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "preserveSymlinks": true,

    "preserveValueImports": true,
    "ignoreDeprecations": "5.0",

    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "esModuleInterop": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,
    "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "importsNotUsedAsValues": "error",
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "isolatedModules": true
  }
}



what typings for node do you have installed?

What's the best way to see which typings for node I have installed?
I have these packages types in my package.json
    "@types/find-config": "^1.0.1",
    "@types/luxon": "^3",
    "@types/pg": "^8.10.2",
    "@types/semver": "^7",
    "@types/diff": "^5",


I ended up solving this by deleting node_modules/ and reinstalling.

You need to add missing dependency to your project: @types/node type definitions for the node.
yarn add @types/node

This should solve your problem
